# Trouble with nested Json data

Tags: json, xcode, swift

I'm having a ton of trouble trying to access the nested json data (pasted at the bottom).  I'm able write:

```
 var dataResults = jsonResult["data"] as NSDictionary
```

In order to create a dictionary containing the data within "data", however, Xcode will not allow me to call on anything within "data" such as the information within "current_condition". I've tried to make current_condition it's own dictionary like so:

```
var results = dataResults["current_condition"] as NSDictionary
```

But it would seem that this is turning up as nil

I have also attempted accessing using the standard method for calling nested loops:

```
var dataResults = jsonResult["data"]["current_condition"] as NSDictionary
```

But this results in a compiler error.

Any help? Much appreciated!

Json data:

```
{
data =     {
    "current_condition" =         (
                    {
            cloudcover = 0;
            humidity = 68;
            "observation_time" = "01:39 AM";
            precipMM = "0.0";
            pressure = 1017;
            "temp_C" = 20;
            "temp_F" = 68;
            visibility = 10;
            weatherCode = 143;
            weatherDesc =                 (
                                    {
                    value = Mist;
                }
            );
            weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0006_mist.png";
                }
            );
            winddir16Point = NE;
            winddirDegree = 50;
            windspeedKmph = 7;
            windspeedMiles = 4;
        }
    );
    request =         (
                    {
            query = "London, United Kingdom";
            type = City;
        }
    );
    weather =         (
                    {
            date = "2014-07-25";
            precipMM = "1.5";
            tempMaxC = 27;
            tempMaxF = 81;
            tempMinC = 14;
            tempMinF = 57;
            weatherCode = 353;
            weatherDesc =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "Light rain shower";
                }
            );
            weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png";
                }
            );
            winddir16Point = NE;
            winddirDegree = 54;
            winddirection = NE;
            windspeedKmph = 15;
            windspeedMiles = 10;
        },
                    {
            date = "2014-07-26";
            precipMM = "5.8";
            tempMaxC = 28;
            tempMaxF = 83;
            tempMinC = 16;
            tempMinF = 61;
            weatherCode = 176;
            weatherDesc =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "Patchy rain nearby";
                }
            );
            weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png";
                }
            );
            winddir16Point = NNE;
            winddirDegree = 12;
            winddirection = NNE;
            windspeedKmph = 11;
            windspeedMiles = 7;
        },
                    {
            date = "2014-07-27";
            precipMM = "0.2";
            tempMaxC = 26;
            tempMaxF = 80;
            tempMinC = 13;
            tempMinF = 55;
            weatherCode = 116;
            weatherDesc =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "Partly Cloudy";
                }
            );
            weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png";
                }
            );
            winddir16Point = NW;
            winddirDegree = 321;
            winddirection = NW;
            windspeedKmph = 14;
            windspeedMiles = 9;
        },
                    {
            date = "2014-07-28";
            precipMM = "1.9";
            tempMaxC = 26;
            tempMaxF = 78;
            tempMinC = 12;
            tempMinF = 54;
            weatherCode = 116;
            weatherDesc =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "Partly Cloudy";
                }
            );
            weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png";
                }
            );
            winddir16Point = N;
            winddirDegree = 351;
            winddirection = N;
            windspeedKmph = 13;
            windspeedMiles = 8;
        },
                    {
            date = "2014-07-29";
            precipMM = "0.0";
            tempMaxC = 28;
            tempMaxF = 82;
            tempMinC = 16;
            tempMinF = 60;
            weatherCode = 113;
            weatherDesc =                 (
                                    {
                    value = Sunny;
                }
            );
            weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png";
                }
            );
            winddir16Point = NNW;
            winddirDegree = 329;
            winddirection = NNW;
            windspeedKmph = 13;
            windspeedMiles = 8;
        }
    );
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, I have a sample weather app that I converted to Swift. I get my data elsewhere, but I found this library to be a great way to deal with JSON in Swift: https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json/. Much cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `subscript` in `Dictionary` returns an optional:

```
subscript (key: KeyType) -> ValueType?
```

Meaning you have to unwrap the optional before you can downcast:

```
let dataResults = jsonResult["data"]! as NSDictionary
let results = dataResults["current_condition"]! as NSDictionary
```

As of Beta 3 you can access the value directly without downcasting, like this:

```
let dataResults = jsonResult["data"]!
let results = dataResults["current_condition"]
```

However I would suggest you wrap it around an if-let to make sure you don't unwrap nil values.

Comment: Hey, so I tried both of your solutions, I wound up with the following problems: When I tried your first fix, I get a runtime error- EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386_BPT,subcode=0x0)  When I try your second fix, I get a compiler error and I get the "SourceKit terminated" message

Comment: Can you please update your question with how you populate the jsonResult and I'll have another look. Thanks.